# How to interpret the tuning result of the GraphLearner with branches in mlr3?

Tags: r, machine-learning, mlr3

Recently I follow some tutorials to learn how to use the GraphLearner in mlr3. But I am still confused about the tuning result of the GraphLearner with branch. I set up a simple example, Here is my codes:

```
# Create a Graph with Branch
graph_branch <- 
  po("branch", c("nop", "pca", "scale"), id = "preprocess_branch") %>>%
  gunion(list(
    po("nop"),
    po("pca", id = "pca1"),
    po("scale") %>>% po("pca", id = "pca2")
    )) %>>%
  po("unbranch", id = "preprocess_unbranch") %>>%
  po("branch", c("classif.kknn", "classif.featureless"), id = "lrn_branch") %>>%
  gunion(list(
    lrn("classif.kknn", predict_type = "prob"),
    lrn("classif.featureless", predict_type = "prob")
    )) %>>%
  po("unbranch", id = "lrn_unbranch")

# Convert a graph to a learner
graph_branch_lrn <- as_learner(graph_branch)
graph_branch_lrn$graph$plot()
```

[image]

```
# Set the tuning grid
tune_grid <- ParamSet$new(
  list(
  ParamFct$new("preprocess_branch.selection", levels = c("nop", "pca", "scale")),
  ParamInt$new("pca1.rank.", lower = 1, upper = 10),
  ParamInt$new("pca2.rank.", lower = 1, upper = 10),
  ParamFct$new("lrn_branch.selection", levels = c("classif.kknn", "classif.featureless")),
  ParamInt$new("classif.kknn.k", lower = 1, upper = 10)
  ))

# Set the instance
instance_rs <- TuningInstanceSingleCrit$new(
  task = task_train,
  learner = graph_branch_lrn,
  resampling = rsmp("cv", folds = 5),
  measure = msr("classif.auc"),
  search_space = tune_grid,
  terminator = trm("evals", n_evals = 20)
  )

# Random search tuning
tuner_rs <- tnr("random_search")
plan(multisession, workers = 5)
set.seed(100)
tuner_rs$optimize(instance_rs)
plan(sequential)
```

The best tuning result is:

```
# Check the result
instance_rs$result_learner_param_vals

$preprocess_branch.selection
[1] "nop"

$scale.robust
[1] FALSE

$lrn_branch.selection
[1] "classif.kknn"

$classif.featureless.method
[1] "mode"

$pca1.rank.
[1] 9

$pca2.rank.
[1] 9

$classif.kknn.k
[1] 9
```

I want to know that if it chooses the "nop" branch, why the tuning results of "pca1.rank." and "pca2.rank." appear? I used to consider that the tuning of the GraphLearner with branch will choose the best result according to the branch, for example if the "nop" branch is chosen, the parameters in the other branches will not consider and appear in the process. Do I make something wrong in interpreting the mechanism of GraphLearner tuning or something wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong; the output just shows you the best values for *all* hyperparameters. Not all of them might be relevant -- here, you can simply ignore the values for `scale`, `pca1`, and `pca2`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But if the output shows the best values for all hyperparameters mix from different branches, how do I know which branch should I choose?  For example, why should I choose the "nop" branch but not the "pca1.rank. = 9" or "scale" → "pca2.rank. = 9"?  Whether should I do some preprocessing on the input data or just leave it "nop"? I am still not so clear.

Comment: I find that I should set dependencies when setting the tuning grid using `tune_grid$add_dep("pca1.rank.", "preprocess_branch.selection", CondEqual$new("pca"))`, `tune_grid$add_dep("pca2.rank.", "preprocess_branch.selection", CondEqual$new("scale"))`, `tune_grid$add_dep("classif.kknn.k", "lrn_branch.selection", CondEqual$new("classif.kknn"))`. After retuning, the `preprocess_branch.selection` is "nop", and `pca1.rank.`, `pca2.rank.` are both "NA" in `instance_rs$result` . But `pca1.rank.` and `pca2.rank.` in `instance_rs$result_learner_param_vals`  are still equal to 9, not "NA" , why?

Comment: The `instance_rs$result_learner_param_vals` is used to finalize the GraphLearner like `graph_branch_lrn$param_set$values <- instance_rs$result_learner_param_vals`, if it is not  consist with the `instance_rs$result`, how can I use it to finalize the learner?

Comment: It is correct to set dependencies. After tuning, `instance_rs$result` should contain `NA`s for the parameters on the unselected branches. The list `instance_rs$result_learner_param_vals` should contain no elements for these parameters. I cannot reproduce the behavior you described on the latest mlr3 and mlr3tuning  CRAN and gh versions. Can you check again in a new session?

Comment: @be-marc After clearing the environment and rerunning the whole pipeline,  `instance_rs$result` and `instance_rs$result_learner_param_vals` become the same. The problem is sovled. Thank you!